# Where is the weather data for the Garmin G1000 retrieved from?

Tags: navigation, weather, flight-planning, crosswind

In a few videos I saw the possibility of looking for example at wind data. Now my question would be where does the G1000 gets the data from?

Comment: Garmin Flight Data Services (GFDS) or Flight Information System-Broadcast (FIS-B), looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is coming from a satellite based XM weather service which provides a variety of weather products on demand to pilots using a G1000 system.